# How do I determine whether the image of a function lies in an algebraic curve?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-geometry, dynamical-systems, algebraic-curves

On p. 2 of the book Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems by Lawrence Perko we define the function

$$x(t) = \left(c_1 e^{-t}, c_2 e^{2t}\right)$$

It is then stated that the curve defined by such a function lies on the algebraic curve

$$ y= \frac{c_1^2 c_2}{x^2} $$

It does indeed seem that this is the case. While it is relatively simple to verify such a fact, I have no idea how I would have gone about deducing such a thing given only the definition of $x$. Thus my question is:

How can I deduce whether or not a function lies in an algebraic curve (or surface etc) and if it does, how can I determine which algebraic curve (or surface) it lies in?

Comment: In general, that's a very hard question to answer. To test whether the curve defined by the first equation lies on the second, you substite, i.e., replace $y$ by $c_2 e^{2t}$ and $x$ by $c_1 e^{-t}$ in the second equation, getting
$
c_2 e^{2t} = \frac{xc_1^2 c_2}{(c_1 e^{-t})^2}
$
which can be simplified to 
$
c_2 e^{2t} = \frac{c_1^2 c_2}{c_1^2 e^{-2t}} = \frac{c_2}{e^{-2t}}= {c_2}{e^{2t}},
$

which is always true (although $c_2 \ne 0$ was used in the simplification). So "verification" isn't too hard. But given *any* curve, finding an algebraic curve/surface that it lies on is really hard.

Comment: Also, this conclusion was done in a very simple way. Function $X(t)$ is a solution of $\frac{dx}{dt} = - x$, $\frac{dy}{dt} = 2y$ ODE. By division you can obtain ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2y}{-x}$ which is separable and has simple solution of form $y = Cx^{-2}$. So, solving ODE this way instantly causes such conclusion.